# Set state when input value changed by a slider - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm using this Foundation slider: [click for doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html). In order to access slider's current value they recommend using hidden input like so:

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="200">
 <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1">
 </span>
 <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
 <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

What I want to do is display the value next to the slider using some variable. My idea is to listen to changes made to the input's value using something like onChange() and setting it to a function that sets the state thus calling render function with an updated value. The problem is that this only works if user enters the value and when it's being altered by the slider it does not call onChange() or any other function I tried. Here's my code:

Function that's supposed to be triggered:

```
  onValueChange: function () {
   this.setState({
    setTemp: this.refs.location.value
   });
 },
```

Inside render function:

```
var {setTemp} = this.state;

<div className="controlPanel">
    <div className="slider vertical" data-slider data-initial-start={curTemp} data-step="5" data-end="110" data-vertical="true">
         <span className="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabIndex="1" onClick={this.onValueChange}></span>
         <span className="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
         <input id="tempInput" type="hidden" ref="location" onChange={this.onValueChange}/>
    </div>
 </div>
      <div className="currentStats">
        Temp: {setTemp}
      </div>
```

I tried adding onClick, onMove functions on the slider itself and it does work but I want the function to be called only when the slider's **value** is changed

Any ideas?

Comment: react-slider code that you can refer to - https://github.com/mpowaga/react-slider/blob/master/react-slider.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its documentation, you can listen to moved.zf.slider event.

```
$('.slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function() {
    // update state
}
```

Or you can bind the slider to external input and get the value of input:

```
<div class="small-10 columns">
  <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50">
    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput1"></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small-2 columns">
  <input type="number" id="sliderOutput1">
</div>
```

reference:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#js-events

Comment: Where do I call the jQuery function? I tried calling it inside ComponentDidMount function - am I doing it wrong? The second option means that the Value is being displayed in the Input field and you can control that but the function still isn't called when the slider is moved.

Comment: @jwm0 ComponentDidMount function seems to be the right one. https://codepen.io/sam_lee/pen/owNppV I haven't tried based on reactjs, but this should work in the same way. For the second option, I guess you can just add onChange to input component.

Comment: The jquery method worked! Thank you, finnaly got it working. By the way, the page I'm creating is sort of a control panel and there will be lots of slides and switches. Is it a good idea to keep state of all the controls in one component (class) or should I further divide the component into smaller ones (one slider being one class)?